# Stationary point of $f(\zeta) =\frac{1}{\log{2}} \left[ \log\left(2 - \zeta \right) - \left( \frac {1-\zeta} {2-\zeta} \right) \zeta \right]$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let us define the following:

$$\zeta(\beta;\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\left[
1+\alpha+\beta 
-
\sqrt{4\beta+(\alpha+\beta-1)^2}
\right]$$

$$F(\beta;\alpha) = f(\zeta) = 
%%%
\frac{1}{\log{2}}
\left[
\log\left(2 - \zeta \right)
-
\left(
\frac
{1-\zeta}
{2-\zeta}
\right)
\zeta 
\right]$$

and

$$G(\beta;\alpha) = \frac{1}{\beta}F(\beta;\alpha)$$

where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}^+$. It can be shown that $\zeta,F,f\in(0,1)$ and $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$.

I want to find for what $\alpha$  $\exists\beta^*>0:$
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial \beta}(\beta^*;\alpha) = 0$$

I have attempted multiple ways of doing this, I will give my working for the brute force derivative below, but first I would like to ask why the following method is incorrect:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial \beta}
%%%
&=
%%%
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
\frac{1}{\beta}
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)
\right)\\
%%%
&=
%%%
\frac{1}{\beta}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)
\right)
-
\frac{1}{\beta^2}
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial \beta} = 0
%%%
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
%%%
\beta
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)
\right)
&=
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)\\
%%%
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
%%%
\frac{
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)
\right)
}
{F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)}
&=
\frac{1}{\beta}\\
%%%
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
%%%
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\log{F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)}
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\log{\beta}\\
%%%
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
%%%
\log{F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)}
&=
\log{\beta}
+c\\
%%%
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
%%%
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)
&=
A(\alpha)\beta
\end{align}

Therefore we can write
\begin{align}
A(\alpha) = F\left(1;\alpha\right)
\end{align}

This isn't holding under a numerical check, can't spot a mistake. Also apologies I could not properly define the problem in the title.

Here are my brute force derivative workings:

Consider
\begin{align}
\log{2}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)
\right)
%%%
&=
%%%
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
\log\left(2 - \zeta \right)
\right)
-
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left[
\left(
\frac
{1-\zeta}
{2-\zeta}
\right)
\zeta
\right]\\
%%%
&=
%%%
-
\frac{1}{2 - \zeta}
\frac{\partial\zeta}{\partial\beta}
-
\left(
\frac
{1-\zeta}
{2-\zeta}
\right)
\frac{\partial\zeta}{\partial\beta}
-
\zeta
\left[
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
\frac
{1-\zeta}
{2-\zeta}
\right)
\right]\\
%%%
&=
%%%
-
\frac{1}{2 - \zeta}
\frac{\partial\zeta}{\partial\beta}
-
\left(
\frac
{1-\zeta}
{2-\zeta}
\right)
\frac{\partial\zeta}{\partial\beta}
-
\zeta
\left[
-
\left(
\frac
{1}
{(2-\zeta)^2}
\right)
\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial \beta}
\right]\\
%%%
&=
%%%
\left\{
\frac
{\zeta}
{(2-\zeta)^2}
-
\frac{1}{2 - \zeta}
-
\frac
{1-\zeta}
{2-\zeta}
\right\}
\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial \beta}\\
%%%
&=
%%%
\left\{
\frac
{\zeta}{(2-\zeta)^2}
-
\frac{2-\zeta}{2-\zeta}
\right\}
\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial \beta}\\
%%%
&=
%%%
\left\{
\frac
{\zeta}{(2-\zeta)^2}
-
1
\right\}
\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial \beta}
\end{align}

Next consider
\begin{align}
2\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial \beta}
%%%
&=
%%%
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
1+\alpha+\beta 
-
\sqrt{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^2+2(\beta-\alpha)+1}
\right)\\
%%%
&=
%%%
1
-
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\sqrt{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^2+2(\beta-\alpha)+1}\\
%%%
&=
%%%
1
-
\frac{1}{2}
\frac
{
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^2+2(\beta-\alpha)+1
\right)
}
{\sqrt{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^2+2(\beta-\alpha)+1}}\\
%%%
&=
%%%
1
-
\frac{1}{2}
\frac
{
2\left(\alpha+\beta\right)+2
}
{\sqrt{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^2+2(\beta-\alpha)+1}}\\
%%%
&=
%%%
1
-
\frac
{
1+\alpha+\beta
}
{\sqrt{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^2+2(\beta-\alpha)+1}}
\end{align}

Note that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^2+2(\beta-\alpha)+1}
%%%
&=
%%%
1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta
\end{align}

therefore
\begin{align}
2\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial \beta}
%%%
&=
%%%
1
-
\frac
{
1+\alpha+\beta
}
{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}\\
%%%
&=
%%%
\frac{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}
-
\frac{1+\alpha+\beta}{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}\\
%%%
&=
%%%
-\frac{2\zeta}{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}\\
%%%%
\therefore\quad
\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial \beta} &= -\frac{\zeta}{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)
\right)
%%%
&=
%%%
\frac{1}{\log{2}}
\left\{
\frac
{\zeta}{(2-\zeta)^2}
-
1
\right\}
\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial \beta}\\
%%%
&=
%%%
\frac{1}{\log{2}}
\left\{
1-\frac{\zeta}{(2-\zeta)^2}
\right\}
\frac{\zeta}{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
\beta
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}
\left(
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)
\right)
&=
F\left(\beta;\alpha\right)\\
%%%
\Rightarrow\quad
%%%
\frac{1}{\log{2}}
\left\{
1-\frac{\zeta}{(2-\zeta)^2}
\right\}
\frac{\beta\zeta}{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}
%%%
&=
%%%
\frac{1}{\log{2}}
\left[
\log\left(2 - \zeta \right)
-
\left(
\frac
{1-\zeta}
{2-\zeta}
\right)
\zeta 
\right]\\
%%%
\Rightarrow\quad
%%%
\left\{
1-\frac{\zeta}{(2-\zeta)^2}
\right\}
\frac{\beta\zeta}{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}
%%%
&=
%%%
\log\left(2 - \zeta \right)
-
\left(
\frac
{1-\zeta}
{2-\zeta}
\right)
\zeta\\
%%%
\Rightarrow\quad
%%%
\left\{
\frac{(2-\zeta)^2-\zeta}{(2-\zeta)^2}
\right\}
\frac{\beta\zeta}{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}
%%%
&=
%%%
\log\left(2 - \zeta \right)
-
\left(
\frac
{1-\zeta}
{2-\zeta}
\right)
\zeta\\
%%%
\Rightarrow\quad
%%%
\left\{
\frac
{\zeta^2-5\zeta+4}
{2-\zeta}
\right\}
\frac{\beta\zeta}{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}
%%%
&=
%%%
(2-\zeta)\log\left(2 - \zeta \right)
-
(1-\zeta)\zeta\\
%%%
\Rightarrow\quad
%%%
\frac
{\beta\zeta(\zeta-4)(\zeta-1)}
{1+\alpha+\beta-2\zeta}
%%%
&=
%%%
(2-\zeta)^2\log\left(2 - \zeta \right)
-
(1-\zeta)(2-\zeta)\zeta
\end{align}